# Why passport doesn't work with cookieSession()?

Tags: node.js

I am working on facebook authorization and found that passport doesn't work with cookieSession() only with session(). In first case req.user is always undefined. Is it possible to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Are you still able to reproduce this with the latest version of Express?  I've seen one other report of this, but it was a while back, so my suspicion is that it was a bug in Connect that has since been addressed.

If you can reproduce it on an earlier version, what version is that?

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here, with express 3.3.4 (last version). Any solution?

Comment: I'm using 3.4.4 with passport 0.1.17, and the same problem occurs. I tried reducing version of express all the way down to 3.0.0, and tried to reduce passport version up to 0.1.5, without any improvement. Every time I tried to use express.session(), and with this it works like a charm.